# how to align contect in column file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i have a list of processes with the following content:

```
avahi- daemon 

S (sleeping)

753

1

115

122
```

The first line is the name of the process , the second is the state, third the pid and then PPID,UID,GID respectively.
This list has been extracted using the following command:

```sh
awk  -F":" 'NR==1 {print $2} NR==6 {print $2} NR==7 {print $2} NR==9 {print $2} NR==10 {print $2} NR==3 {print $2}' /proc/PID/status
```

i would like to align this content and have an output in columns like this for all the processes:

Name PID PPID UID GID STATE

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply print the desired format directly from your Awk script?

Comment: no there isnt. Simply i dont know exactly how to use awk to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily refactor your Awk script to produce the desired format.

```
awk  -F":" 'NR==1 {name=$2}
  NR==3 {state=$2}
  NR==6 {pid=$2}
  NR==7 {ppid=$2}
  NR==9 {uuid=$2}
  NR==10 {gid=$2
    print name, pid, ppid, uid, gid, state }' /proc/PID/status
```

If you want tab-delimited output, add `-v ORS="\t"` before the `-F` option.

Comment: How can i match the process which it has S (sleeping) as  state?

Comment: Trivially `if(state == "S") print` instead of just `print`; or `if(state ~ /S/)` to use a regular expression. If you want to use Awk, maybe read a basic tutorial; you can pick up the essentials of the language in less than an hour.

Comment: sorry to be a bother but i am still having an issue with awk. i tried awk -F":" 'NR==1 {name=$2} 
          NR==3 {state=$2} 
          NR==6 {pid=$2} 
          NR==7 {ppid=$2} 
          NR==9 {uuid=$2} 
          NR==10 {gid=$2 match($state,/S (sleeping)/)
          print name, pid, ppid, uid, gid, state }' /proc/PID/status  and i dont know what it goes wrong

Comment: You seem to be missing an `if`, and the dollar sign before `state` is wrong (dollar in Awk means pick up the field with that number). You want `... { gid=$2; if (state ~ /S/) print name pid, ppid, uid, gid, state }' /prod/PID/status`